# Customizing PDFTextStripper PDFbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

`PDFTextStripper` has a functionality to extract text from the whole document, is there a way to extract text only after a certain value when the value is recognized, for example :

```
A B C D G   1 line

A B C D G   2 line

A B C D G   3 line

QUANTITY  4 line
```

I would like to start to extract text after it finds Quantity(String)
If anyone dealt with PDFBox and have some suggestion, it would be much appreciated

Or is it possible to add to the list only when it hits a line after a value that text will contain?

Comment: How about searching in the extracted text for your marker words and dropping everything before that? The stripper is not really a good place for that functionality because content in a content stream can come in any order, it does not necessarily come in the order you perceive. Thus, the stripper can sort by position. This in turn means, that all content must be extracted and kept at least until that sorting happens.

Comment: @mkl you are right , thanks for your comment, I have posted an answer

Comment: Strictly speaking David in his answer provides an option, overriding `writeString`. Usually, though, you are more flexible with the whole page text at your hands and regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to capture whole text and then create a Pattern that says -> `"DESCRIPTION\\s*Reference\\s*QUANTITY(.*)"` so basically i want to capture everything on a single page from the mentioned above

1. create a function that would take `String` text as a parameter  locate a single `matcher.group(1)`, and return `String` or `Optional<String>`
2. create a Pattern and tell that pattern with regex where would you like to start capturing from

Answer (score 0):

You can either capture the whole text as stated by Artjom, or you can create a custom PDFTextStripper that extends from PDFTextStripper and override the function where the text is parsed, like this

```
@Override
protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) {
    ...
}
```

and then use the TextPositions to determinate where you should start parsing